# Can we have more file descriptors other than the usual stdin/stdout/stderr (0, 1, 2) ones?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Can we assign to any file a file descriptor number actually?

Comment: Within broad limits, **yes**.  Broad limits include keeping an eye on `ulimit -n` (the maximum number of open file descriptors allowed).

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can. But it is up to the program in question if it does something with it.

```
$ cat fd.c 
int main()
{
    write(5,"test\n",5);
}
$ gcc fd.c
$ ./a.out 5> file
$ cat file
test
$ ./a.out 5>&1
test
$ ./a.out 
$
```

In that last case, the output to fd 5 vanished.

`openssl` uses this to allow passphrases and such to be passed to the process without using regular `argv` (which may expose them).

**update** the input case:

```
$ cat fd_in.c 
int main()
{
    unsigned char buf[16];
    write(5,buf,read(6,buf,16));
}
$ gcc fd_in.c 
$ ./a.out 6< file 5>&1
test
```

(`file` contained `test\n` from the previous example)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, in bash you can use `file descriptor` for reading and/or writing and can use any number. **However**, since **0**, **1** and **2** is used for **STDIN**, **STDOUT** and **STDERR**, we avoid those. Also, numbers **greater than 9** are used internally so we tend to avoid those as well.

This is how we can open a file descriptor to do the following:

#### Read:

```
fd<source
```

#### Write:

```
fd>source
```

#### Read/Write:

```
fd<>source
```

where `fd` is a digit that describes `file descriptor` and `source` can be either a `file` or even another `file descriptor` (though you would add **`&`** before it).

If you are using `exec` for file descriptors then that allows the changes to take effect in the current shell. Otherwise they are local to function or loop.

#### Example 1 -

Following use of fd will be local to while loop and you cannot use it outside:

```
while read line <&3; do 
    echo $line; 
done 3<test.file
```

#### Example 2 -

Following use of fd will be visible in the current shell

```
exec 3<test.file
while read line <&3; do 
    echo $line; 
done
```

Answer (score 1):

As you tagged this with bash, See [AdvancedBash](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17784.html#REDIR1) for the basics.

The section below that link (Example 20-2) has the following

```
LOGFILE=logfile.txt
exec 6>&1           # Link file descriptor #6 with stdout.
                    # Saves stdout.
exec > $LOGFILE     # stdout replaced with file "logfile.txt".
```

Is that what you are looking for?