# pros and cons of file descriptors over regular pipe redirection?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

What are the pros and cons of file descriptors over regular pipe redirection (e.g. `ls | wc`)?

Why prefer File Descriptors stdin 0, stdout 1, stderr 2 etc?
Any idea?

Comment: I don't understand what you're comparing here.  Please give a concrete example.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more? in this form it is not really a valid question.

Comment: This seems to be a follow on to the OPs previous question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903612/can-we-have-more-file-descriptors-other-than-the-usual-stdin-stdout-stderr-0-1

Answer (score 2):

Pipes, specifically anonymous pipes, as in your question, (`|`) allow you to pass data directly between two programs (or more, in a chain) without having any intermediate files on disk. It's convenient to not have to deal with creating and deleting such temporary files, and can be faster, since no files have to be written to disk, since disk I/O is (relatively) slow.

Using different file descriptors (particularly `stdout` and `stderr`, which are 1 and 2, respectively) allow you to handle the `stdout` or `stderr` stream from a program to some file.  The ability to choose a file descriptor is only really needed with programs that do use `stderr`, otherwise just redirecting to stdout (with `>` or `1>`) is sufficient.

A contrived example of using `stderr` *and* a pipe is like this:

```
# ./some-program 2> errors
# cat errors | wc -l
```

This would print out the `stderr` from `some-program` to the file `errors`, and then pipe the output of `cat errors` to `wc -l`, which is the number of lines in `errors`.  **Note that you just about never want to use `wc` this way, and can just do `wc -l errors`. This is just for illustration.**

Comment: advantages of file descriptors over regular anonymous pipe redirection, I don't see any. Pipes are better all the time, should I conclude?

Answer (score 2):

Piping input from one process to another involves file descriptors; the standard output (fd = 1) of the first process is connected to the standard input (fd = 0) of the next process in the pipeline.

The alternative to using pipes is temporary files:

```
ls > tmp.1
wc < tmp.1
rm -f tmp.1
```

The advantages of pipes over this are manifold, but include:

- No temporary files to get left around.
- No code needed to try and clean temporary files up in case of interrupts, etc.
- The processes can work in parallel (especially advantageous on multi-core machines).
- No need to invent file names.
- Less to type.

The decision to make file descriptors 0, 1, 2 into standard input, output and error was very valuable.  The mapping of the numbers to the streams is arbitrary, but as long as everyone agrees, perfectly effective.