# Read from alternate file descriptor into shell variable

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, file-descriptor, io-redirection

I have a program that prompts the user for a password and derives a key from it, which I later need to pass on stdin to a decryption program.  I don't want to store the key in a file at any time, so I am instead looking to pass it in a variable.

The password program needs to display a password prompt, so I can't read from its stdout into a variable without losing the prompt.  I know from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8903612/5472899) that I can capture output from alternate descriptors, and from [this](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) that very elaborate redirection and piping is possible, but I'm failing to put it all together.

The password program is mine, so I can make it write to an alternate descriptor of my choice, say `3`.  The following illustrates what I would like to do, but I know it is incorrect.  How can I fix this?

```
read key < <&3 $(password_program) 
# other operations ...
echo $key | decryption_program -
```

Comment: `read -u 3` should work

Comment: As should `read key <&3`

Comment: @william: that's how to get `read` to read from the shell's fd 3. But how d o propose to make `password_program`'s output show up on the shell's fd 3? It's clear how `password_program` could write to its own fd 3, but that doesn't help much.

Answer (score 3):

If you are writing the password program, the simplest (and usual) solution is to write the prompt to `stderr`, leaving `stdout` free. So you can then echo the password to `stdout` and capture it into a variable.

Alternatively, you could write the prompt and read the password from `/dev/tty`.

For the simplest solution, if you are using bash and all your password reader does is print a prompt and read a password without echoing it, you could just use `IFS= read -srp "prompt: " passwd`

Comment: Thanks.  Your suggestion of writing the prompt to stderr and the key to stdout does work in this situation, so I'll upvote, but I'm still hoping somebody can tell me how to make this work with an alternate file descriptor for a more general solution. The `IFS= read -srp "prompt: " passwd` approach won't work for me because my password program has to perform additional processing to derive the key.

Answer (score 2):

I think, this should do your trick in bash:

```
exec 4>&1
key=$(password_program 3>&1 >&4-)
exec 4>&-
```

It works as follows: The first exec duplicates file descriptor 1 (`stdout`) as descriptor 4. Then because of the `$()` syntax, `password_program` is executed in a subshell, whose `stdout` will go into the variable `key`. But we let that subshell do some descriptor mangling, before actually executing `password_program`: Descriptor 3 is opened as a copy of descriptor 1, so that `password_program` can write its results to descriptor 3. Then descriptor 4 (our saved "copy" of the original `stdout`) is moved to descriptor 1. So the result is: `password_program` will run with its `stdout` as the same file (or tty etc.), that the shell was started with. The final command then gets rid again of the descriptor 4 in the main shell.

If it is acceptable for you to clone stderr instead of stdout as input to your `password_program`, you could also do:

```
key=$(password_program 3>&1 >&2)
```